# Alternative to nested loop in python

Tags: python, loops, nested, distribution

I wrote a function U_p_law which takes 2 probability density functions (L_P and L_Q) of 2 players and 2 integer values that define how often each player one when they played each other.

The calculation is for now done over 2 nested loops which each index over omega (an array from 0 to 3500 with step 10). The function returns the normalized utility function of the first player:

```
def U_p_law(W,L,L_P, L_Q):
    omega = np.arange(0, 3501, 10)

    U_p = np.zeros_like(omega, dtype=float)

    for p_idx, p in enumerate(omega):
        for q_idx, q in enumerate(omega):
            U_p[p_idx] += (probability_of_loss(q - p)**W * probability_of_loss(p - q)**L * L_Q[q_idx] * L_P[p_idx])

    normalization_factor = np.sum(U_p)
    U_p /= normalization_factor

    return omega, U_p

omega, U_p = U_p_law(W, L, L_P, L_Q)
```

Since these nested loops are time-consuming in computation I wondered if there is a better way to write this function?

The nested loop approach gives me the desired result but takes computation time.
I pass these values into the function:

```
P_mean = 1500
P_std = 100
Q_mean = 1500
Q_std = 100
W = 1  # Number of matches won by P
L = 0  # Number of matches lost by P
L_P = np.exp(-0.5 * ((np.arange(0, 3501, 10) - P_mean) / P_std)**2) / (P_std * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
L_Q = np.exp(-0.5 * ((np.arange(0, 3501, 10) - Q_mean) / Q_std)**2) / (Q_std * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))

def probability_of_loss(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(x / 67))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe there's something in `statpy` that will calculate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can speedup the function using [numba](/questions/tagged/numba). Here is an example + simple benchmark:

```
from timeit import timeit

from numba import njit, prange

P_mean = 1500
P_std = 100
Q_mean = 1500
Q_std = 100
W = 1  # Number of matches won by P
L = 0  # Number of matches lost by P
L_P = np.exp(-0.5 * ((np.arange(0, 3501, 10) - P_mean) / P_std) ** 2) / (
    P_std * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)
)
L_Q = np.exp(-0.5 * ((np.arange(0, 3501, 10) - Q_mean) / Q_std) ** 2) / (
    Q_std * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)
)


def probability_of_loss(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(x / 67))


def U_p_law(W, L, L_P, L_Q):
    omega = np.arange(0, 3501, 10)

    U_p = np.zeros_like(omega, dtype=float)

    for p_idx, p in enumerate(omega):
        for q_idx, q in enumerate(omega):
            U_p[p_idx] += (
                probability_of_loss(q - p) ** W
                * probability_of_loss(p - q) ** L
                * L_Q[q_idx]
                * L_P[p_idx]
            )

    normalization_factor = np.sum(U_p)
    U_p /= normalization_factor

    return omega, U_p


@njit
def probability_of_loss_numba(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(x / 67))


@njit
def U_p_law_numba(W, L, L_P, L_Q):
    omega = np.arange(0, 3501, 10, dtype=np.float64)

    U_p = np.zeros_like(omega)

    for p_idx, p in enumerate(omega):
        for q_idx, q in enumerate(omega):
            U_p[p_idx] += (
                probability_of_loss_numba(q - p) ** W
                * probability_of_loss_numba(p - q) ** L
                * L_Q[q_idx]
                * L_P[p_idx]
            )

    normalization_factor = np.sum(U_p)
    U_p /= normalization_factor

    return omega, U_p


@njit(parallel=True)
def U_p_law_numba_parallel(W, L, L_P, L_Q):
    omega = np.arange(0, 3501, 10, dtype=np.float64)

    U_p = np.zeros_like(omega)

    for p_idx in prange(len(omega)):
        p = omega[p_idx]
        for q_idx in prange(len(omega)):
            q = omega[q_idx]
            U_p[p_idx] += (
                probability_of_loss_numba(q - p) ** W
                * probability_of_loss_numba(p - q) ** L
                * L_Q[q_idx]
                * L_P[p_idx]
            )

    normalization_factor = np.sum(U_p)
    U_p /= normalization_factor

    return omega, U_p


omega_1, U_p_1 = U_p_law(W, L, L_P, L_Q)
omega_2, U_p_2 = U_p_law_numba(W, L, L_P, L_Q)
omega_3, U_p_3 = U_p_law_numba_parallel(W, L, L_P, L_Q)

assert np.allclose(omega_1, omega_2)
assert np.allclose(omega_1, omega_3)
assert np.allclose(U_p_1, U_p_2)
assert np.allclose(U_p_1, U_p_3)

t1 = timeit("U_p_law(W, L, L_P, L_Q)", number=10, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("U_p_law_numba(W, L, L_P, L_Q)", number=10, globals=globals())
t3 = timeit("U_p_law_numba_parallel(W, L, L_P, L_Q)", number=10, globals=globals())

print("10 calls using vanilla Python     :", t1)
print("10 calls using Numba              :", t2)
print("10 calls using Numba (+ parallel) :", t3)
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 5700x):

```
10 calls using vanilla Python     : 2.4276352748274803
10 calls using Numba              : 0.013957140035927296
10 calls using Numba (+ parallel) : 0.003793451003730297
```

- Speedup ~170x using simple Numba JIT.
- Speedup **~640x** using multithreaded Numba JIT.